# Bind string based SVGs to a UWP application

Tags: c#, .net, image, uwp, desktop

I am new in UWP app development and looking for a way to bind string based SVG to a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) page. And I wanted to show that string based SVG by using Image tag of UWP page (XAML layout). The SVG will be represented in SVG markup language like:

```
dataBindedModel.svg = “<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; width="500" height="500">
<circle cx="250" cy="250" r="210" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="8"/>
</svg>”;
```

For that I need to use {x:Bind} in the XAML, but not sure how to bind this.
Potential XAML Code will be like:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImageView" Source="{x:Bind ...required area...”}>
```

**Update**:

My MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        SVGModel dataBindedModel = new SVGModel();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            dataBindedModel.SVGString = File.ReadAllText("test.xml");
            this.DataContext = dataBindedModel;
        }
    }
    public class SVGModel
    {
        public SVGModel() { }
        public SVGModel(string svg)
        {
            SVGString = svg;
        }
        public string SVGString { get; set; }

    }
```

My **MainPage.xaml**:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:SVGImageConverter x:Key="MyConvert" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Image x:Name="MyImageView" Source="{x:Bind dataBindedModel.SVGString,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource MyConvert }}" />
    </Grid>
```

My **test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg  width="500" height="500">
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="210" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="8"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What you have is just text, not an image. Assigning some text to an `Image` property won't render it. `<Image Source="Assets/mysvg.svg"/>` works because the runtime will use the [SvgImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource?view=winrt-20348) to convert between what's recognized as a path to an `svg` file and the `Image` property

Comment: Where does the SVG come from? A text file? Resource? In that case you can just pass the correct path to `Source`. If it's a string generated at runtime, you can bind to an SvgImageSource and load the data with [SetSourceAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource.setsourceasync?view=winrt-20348#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_SvgImageSource_SetSourceAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - My SVG is in the XML format (test.xml see above). I have created a xml file paste my SVG xml into it. And I am reading this xml in SVGString property of SVGModel class in the constructor of MainPage.xaml.cs. (see above) 
But getting some exception in order to run the code.

Comment: `My SVG is in the XML format` given that SVG *is* XML that doesn't say anything. Have you tried saving the file with an `svg` extension and using it the way the linked docs show? Besides, where is that `test.xml` file? The path is relative which means the application will try to find it in tis executable folder, wherever that is. Windows Apps are sandboxed which means the current directory isn't where you think it is, and the app can't read anything it wants either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - How I can set SVGString property directly with XML in the ctor of MainPage.xaml.cs. What if I try with:
dataBindedModel.SVGString = "<svg></svg>";
Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried putting the SVG file in your project's `Assets` folder and using that with `Image`? `Assets` is a special folder, containing the files that will be deployed along with the app. A UPW app can read those. Very few other folders can be accessed directly, which means that using `File` or `Directory` methods directly requires special care to use the correct path. It's far easier to use the specialized `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile` classes. Check eg [Enumerate and query files and folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders)

Comment: `any ideas` I posted the link to the docs in the very first comment. `<Image Source="Assets/mysvg.svg"/>` comes from the doc example. Save your SVG file in `Assets` with an `svg` extension and use it. You may be able to save it as `.xml` too, but the correct, recognizable extension is `svg`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I don't want to put my SVG in Assets folder. I want to bind string based SVGs to UWP app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP does not allow binding SVG string directly, it only contains  [`SvgImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource?view=winrt-20348) class, please save as svg file and set it to image control like the following.

```
<Image Source="Assets/mysvg.svg"/>
```

And the other way is use value converter to convert string to `SvgImageSource` for example

```
public class SVGImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public  object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var svg = new SvgImageSource();
        try
        {
            var svgBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(value.ToString(), BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
       
            using (var stream = svgBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                 svg.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream()).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return svg;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Image x:Name="MyImageView" Source="{x:Bind dataBindedModel.svg,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource MyConvert }}" />
```

Please note: please make sure your svg string is correct svg type.

Comment: Nico Zhu - MSFT  - Thanks for your feedback. I have try your solution, but it is not working due to some reason. I have update my question. Please tell what is missing in my code.

Comment: Nico Zhu - MSFT - Can you please try with any other xml string of your choice. I want to run through this binding. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will make sample for you, please wait a moment.

Comment: Let me check. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233001/discussion-between-hassan-iftikhar-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: Hi, Nico Zhu, I'm also interested in your sample, can you please share with me, because it is no more accesible